# Multi-dimensional inputs in Chainer

Tags: python, neural-network, chainer

I'm trying to build a neural network with Chainer that takes a 4-dimensional numpy array as an input.

I know that, according to [this publication](https://aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI17/paper/view/14396/13758), that is feasible. However, I don't see the way to build it anywhere in the [datasets documentation](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/datasets.html).

Does anyone know how to build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any N-dimensional input as long as the input and output data have the same length:

```
from chainer.datasets import split_dataset_random, TupleDataset

X = [
    [[.04, .46], [.18, .26]],
    [[.32, .28], [.21, .12]]
]
Y = [.4, .5]  # these are the labels for the X instances, in the same order

train, test = split_dataset_random(TupleDataset(X, Y), int(X.shape[0] * .7))
```

In earlier versions it was required to flatten the arrays into input vectors, but now you can use any N-dimensional numeric array input.

Also, you can use [numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to change the dimensions of the input.